# How to exclude workbench.colorTheme from VS Code Settings Sync?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Is there a way to selectively prevent VS Code from synchronizing the workbench.colorTheme setting between remote and local instances, while keeping all other synchronization settings active?